# How save old ID from MSSQL when insert entity to new DB ORACLE?

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle, hibernate, entity

I write DB migrate utilite.

I have MSSQL DB. Some tables. There are many rows in each table.
I have empty Oracle DB.
I have entities for tables.

I create 2 conections. to MSSQL and to ORACLE.
I create 2 DAO 
In 1 DAO I get all data from MSSQL

```
List<Payment> payments = PaymentService.me().getPayments();
```

After that I persist this list to ORACLE

```
PaymentService.me().persistPayments(payments);
```

But when data insrt to ORACLE table create new ID.

How can I save old ID from MSSQL when data insert to ORACLE?